# How to reduce the bandwidth cost on (Open)Vpn server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, bandwidth, openvpn, orchestration

I have a general question. I made a VPN accessible in mobile platforms, it’s hosted on AWS and everything works fine.
The only problem is it costs a lot of money, (Amazon bill is over $1000) and not because of CPU or memory usage, which are negligible, but because of bandwidth usage.

For our Devops friends- It’s not that I need an orchestrator like Kubernetes, because it works the same way if there are 300 people connected or only 1, everything works fine on a single instance (only the bills changes)

Is there any way to reduce the cost? Did I make the VPN in the correct way? How can I reduce the bandwidth per user?

I used hosted OpenVPN servers on Amazon, Ubuntu 18.04 machine and the clients are mobile applications.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably save a little bit of bandwidth (between the client and server) by enabling compression:

> –compress [algorithm]
>
> Enable a compression algorithm.The algorithm parameter may be “lzo”,
> “lz4”, or empty. LZO and LZ4 are different compression algorithms,
> with LZ4 generally offering the best performance with least CPU usage.
> For backwards compatibility with OpenVPN versions before v2.4, use
> “lzo” (which is identical to the older option “–comp-lzo yes”).

https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/

Comment: Hi, i tried with comp-lzo in both client and server config but it doesn't reduce the bandwidth